# how to fix "Error refreshing Makefiles" error in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I was using an old version of veins in my work (version 4.5) with omnet++ version 5 and SUMO 0.29.0. It was working without problems.

now I want to upgrade to a newer version of veins. I tried both 4.7 and 4.7.1 with the same versions of SUMO and Omnet++. while building the project I get the following error:

Error refreshing Makefiles.

Reason:

Cannot parse /veins/.oppbuildspec

Details:

/veins/.oppbuildspec: unrecognized option: --meta:export-include-path

/veins/.oppbuildspec: unrecognized option: --meta:export-include-path

I don't know how to fix the error. I removed the older veins project from the IDE and the workspace.

I am working on Windows 8.

Comment: Which version of OMNeT++ are you using?

Comment: Omnet++ v5.0. I have already mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

OMNeT++ 5.0 is too old for Veins 4.7.1. See the [download page of Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/download/) for a list of which software versions of OMNeT++ and SUMO each version of Veins is compatible with.

For example, 
- Veins 4.7.1 needs OMNeT++ 5.3 and SUMO 0.32.0.
- Veins 5 alpha 1 needs OMNeT++ 5.4.1 and SUMO 1.0.0.

Comment: thanks, I will try to upgrade both Omnet++ and SUMO.